# Method Range Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting Run-time error "1004' Method "Range" of object '_Global" failed, and the last line of the below code is highlighted.

How can I decipher that error message? Knowing that the error involves a range is as far as I got.

```
   With NewOutput.Sheets(current_sheet_name).Range("print_area")

   Debug.Print NewOutput.Sheets(current_sheet_name).Range("print_area").address
   'Returns $B$1:$L$19

    Debug.Print "Print Area: " & Range("print_area").address
   'Returns Print Area: $B$1:$L$19

    Debug.Print "First row of range: " & Range("print_area").row + 8
    'Returns First row of range: 9

    Set rng = Range(.Cells(.row + 8, .Column + 1) & ":" & .Cells(.Rows.Count + .row - 2, .Column + 1))
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing but try replacing ` & ":" &` by `,`.  I think the syntax you are trying to use is `Set Rng = Range(Cells(R1,C1),Cells(R2,C2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating two cells as if they were the cell addresses. Just use the cells.

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(.row + 8, .Column + 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count + .row - 2, .Column + 1))
```

Comment: Why would `Debug.Print ".cells(.row, .column) = " & .Cells(.row, .Column).address` return `$C$1` when my print_area starts at $B$1 ?

Comment: You are setting `rng` with `.Column + 1`.

Comment: Realized my mistake. I need to do `sheet(name).cells(.row,.column).address`